# error positioning absolute div in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-position

I have a site:

http://iamschicago.com

There are translation links at the top right (english, espanol).  In firefox/safari/good browsers, these appear at the top right, absolutely positioned.

in ie7, they appear much closer to the center top.  This should be an easy fix and is probably just a 'position:relative' on of the parents, but I can't how to fix it.

Our corporate policy doesn't allow me to install the IE web developer extensions, so I can't see how IE is rendering this.

help!

thanks,
Cliff

Comment: Is there a reason there are so many divs wrapping the ul containing your language choice navigation?

Comment: yes, it's a drupal site and those links are 'blocks' provided by the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.art-blockcontent` - remove `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: That was it.  So I guess, IE7 extends that div to a full with and then centers the content?  I'm not sure I understand why it was broken.